# Is there any free Equation Editor Control

Tags: mathematical-typesetting

Hi  am going to do some project there i need

to show integral , sigma, pie , etc.. so is there any equation edtior controls available. so

I have to integrate to my Asp.Net project

I got one editor ie: LAtex Equation editor but it show the html format in the textbox ,and also it show his site name etc on the Equation popup editor, it not free at all.

Any idea pls..

Comment: Not exactly asp.net control, but see this Embeddable WYSIWYG equation editor question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433540/embeddable-wysiwyg-equation-editor