# Embeddable WYSIWYG equation editor

Tags: javascript, flash, editor, mathml, jqmath

do you know of a WYSIWYG equation editor, like DragMath, implemented in javascript/mathml or Flash?

I could embed DragMath as well, but I was wondering if there's a way to have a good WYSIWYG formula editor without requiring the users to run a Java applet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

**Disclaimer: I'm working for [Scolab](http://www.Scolab.com) on one of the editor listed below.**

This list of MathML editors could help you:
http://www.w3.org/Math/Software/mathml_software_cat_editors.html

I know these web-based editors and display engines:

- [**FMath**](http://www.fmath.info) and [**MathMlEditor**](http://code.google.com/p/mathmleditor/) I met the guy maintaining this, he's great.
- [**MathJax**](http://www.mathjax.org/) The author told me he wanted to build an editor in JavaScript. That would be awesome, but I don't know how far he is with it. He's capable.

**[Alfred's Equation Editor (AlfredEq)](http://sharemath.com/AlfredEq-README.html)** - This equation editor was developed by us for [BuzzMath](http://www.BuzzMath.com) and is available for licencing.

- **[Video of an integration of AlfredEq in BuzzMath's edition tools](http://goo.gl/GCkUZ)**

**Screenshot of the editor embedded in [ShareMath.com](http://sharemath.com):**

[image: AlfredEq embedded on a website]

Please post your other findings!

Comment: Sharemath is very good, but their sharing does not work.

Comment: It's more than a week and I've sent 2 emails (with a long time span) using the "Report problem" button. They were pretty long (I did some checks using Firebug to find what's wrong).

Comment: We did something stupid with those reports. We are writing to you to fix it, sorry.

Comment: MathIWYG link is broken :(

Comment: @rvighne Could not find its new home, removed the link :-(

Answer (score 9):

[MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/) is a very good and modern opensource library – it's WYSIWYG but it uses keyboard extensively and if you know LaTeX commands, you can use them too. It's the library used by Symbolab.

[image: MathQuill demo]

---

Or you try the equation editor called [jqmath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html). It's very fast and easy to use, even though it isn't exactly WYSIWYG.

[image: jqmath demo]

Comment: I was looking for something faster, smaller and simpler than MathJAX, JQMath is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

http://mathdox.org/formulaeditor/

this is what I am considering using

Comment: is there anyone maintain the code