# Web-based equation editor to mathml export?

Tags: javascript, html, mathml, formula-editor

I am trying to integrate a mathematical [formula editor](http://www.mathdox.org/formulaeditor/) into a website. I want users to write out an equation in this editor and have the editor export to contain source code in MathML format.

When I play around with the demo and change the equations, the source code does not update to the new equation.

Does this require backend work?

Please no redirections to other formula editors!

Comment: Similar question: [Embeddable WYSIWYG equation editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433540/embeddable-wysiwyg-equation-editor)

Answer (score 1):

For me it does.

```
q²-1/q-1
```

then I use their javascript link

```
javascript:alert(org.mathdox.formulaeditor.FormulaEditor.getEditorByTextArea("formula1").getMathML())
```

and the result is

```
mlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mfrac><mrow><msup><mi>q</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>-</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mrow><mi>q</mi><mo>-</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow></mfrac></math>
```

when I change the formula to

```
q²-1/q-2
```

I get

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mfrac><mrow><msup><mi>q</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>-</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mrow><mi>q</mi><mo>-</mo><mn>2</mn></mrow></mfrac></math>
```

It definitely changes the value. You should provide an example or something similar as referred to SO 'guideline'. You can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour